# Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow

Tags: java, request, binance

I am trying to make a request using this code:

```
public JsonObject account() throws BinanceApiException { 
        return (new Request(baseUrl + "v3/account"))
                .sign(apiKey, secretKey, null).read().asJsonObject();
    }
```

but I get this error:

> BinanceApiException: ERROR: -1021, Timestamp for this request is
>   outside of the recvWindow.

I know that it has something to do with the time synchronization between my computer and the server. I don't get this error every time I run this code. In the past I solved this error by going to Windows settings, Date and Time, Internet Time Settings and synchronize my time to  time.windows.com.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331363/6667442

Comment: I had the same issue and for me the following solved it. I was lucky to have a second laptop which did not give the error. I realized the time on the laptop giving the error was a minute or so out of sync with my other laptop, so I manually changed the time to agree with that other laptop. After doing this I did not get the error again.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a duplicate of [Binance API Error: {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow."}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669914/binance-api-error-code-1021-msgtimestamp-for-this-request-is-outside-of/61779596#61779596).

You need to synchronize time on your computer with Binance rather than with time.windows.com. You can use https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#test-connectivity Check Server Time endpoint:

`GET /api/v3/time`

Another possible reason (at least I faced it) - execution of request in debug mode step by step.

Default recvWindow is 5 seconds. You can also override it if you need.

Comment: Even though my computer time was auto synced, it was a wrong by a minute. In windows 10, I turned off auto-sync time and then turn back it on to correct the system time.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP try $millitime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that, the server expect a 64 bit long unix time stamp, and you most likely send a 32 bit long one, maknig a huge diference, which explain why a huge delay "solves" the problem

Answer (score -1):

```
update api request of python-binance library file path binance/client.py add additional param  recvWindow



def futures_create_order(self, **params):
        """Send in a new order.

        https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

        """
        params['recvWindow'] = 100000000
        print('data params',params)
        return self._request_futures_api('post', 'order', True, data=params)
```

Comment: This is very bad practice. If you use the API for trading, allowing requests to have a massive delay is just wrong. You should fix time synchronization, not allowing it.